# Как пишутся названия экспедиций?

Tags: выбор-слов, ономастика

Названия экспедиций пишутся с большой буквы?

Answer (score 1):

Разные бывают варианты, экспедиция может иметь или не иметь условное название, которое является именем собственным.

Примеры:

**Великая Северная экспедиция** — ряд географических экспедиций, предпринятых русскими моряками вдоль арктического побережья Сибири, к берегам Северной Америки и Японии во второй четверти XVIII века. Имя собственное, пишется с прописной буквы без кавычек.

В литературе встречаются другие её названия — «Вторая Камчатская экспедиция», «Сибирско-Тихоокеанская экспедиция», «Сибирская экспедиция». Имена собственные заключены в кавычки.

А вот Колумб совершил 4 экспедиции, но все они без условных (собственных) названий, написание со строчной буквы.   Модели трех каравелл **первой экспедиции Колумба**. Морской музей в Кальяо. 25 сентября 1493 г. **вторая экспедиция Колумба** вышла из Кадиса.